# Как узнать начальный адрес запускаемого приложения?

Tags: c++, взлом

Решил заняться геймхакингом, взломать косынку. Нашел статический указатель, который равен solitaire.exe+97074..  Как я могу узнать адрес самого solitaire.exe средствами C++?

Comment: Внедрить библиотеку в процесс, и вызвать `GetModuleHandle(NULL);`, полученный `handle` будет являться начальным адресом модуля, к нему подставите оффсет, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Что такое "адрес самого solitaire.exe"?

Comment: я так понимаю адрес в оперативной памяти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я это делал так:

```
bool ProcessClass::FindModuleByName(char *moduleName, DWORD pid)
{
bool result = false;

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid);
if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    MODULEENTRY32 module;
    module.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    if (Module32First(snapshot, &module))
    {
        do
        {
            if (module.th32ProcessID != pid)
                continue;

            if (_stricmp(module.szModule, moduleName) != 0)
                continue;

            m_module = module;
            result = true;
            break;
        } while (Module32Next(snapshot, &module));
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }
}
else
{
    result = false;
}

CloseHandle(snapshot);

return result;
}

MODULEENTRY32 ProcessClass::GetModule()
{
return m_module;
}
......
Process->FindModuleByName(processName, Process->GetPID());
baseAddress = (DWORD)Process->GetModule().modBaseAddr;
```